# How to run a python log in system on a server along side html?

Tags: python, html

I have researched this topic heavily and haven't found a good solution so I am going to ask the question here. I am very inexperienced in web development so just bear that in mind.  I know python pretty well and I want to use those skills to try to make a website log in. What I want to do is have two html input text boxes and when the user clicks "enter", that will trigger python to check if the info is correct.  I am very lost so any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all you will need to enable [cgi-scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) on your server with right permissions and configuration. Then make an ajax call to the python file sitting on your server when the user clicks Enter.

Comment: Why not use JavaScript to check if the info is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what I have learnt so far, I guess that you are trying to implement a simple login function of some website. Maybe you can try Tornado as follows:

```
#just a sample code, cannot run directly  

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.options

from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8080, help="server run on the given port", type=int)

class LoginHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("login.html")

    def post(self):
        username = self.get_argument("username")
        password = self.get_argument("password")

        #some judgement code here:
        #e.g. do some database operations, check if (username, password) pairs are correct
        #if so, set _auth_flag True, otherwise, _auth_flag=False
        [...] 

        if _auth_flag:
            [...]  #if login successfully, execute this part
        else:
            [...] #if login failed, execute

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    app = tornado.web.Application([
           (r'/login', LoginHandler),
          ])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

And the compared login.html file maybe like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is a login test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="/login" method="POST">
            <div class="login_group">
                <label id="login_user">Username:</label>
                <span></span>
                <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="login_group">
                <label id="login_pwd">Passowrd:</label>
                <span></span>
                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
            </div>

            <div class="login_submit">
                <button type="submit">Enter</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tornado is not only a simple web framework with clean-up code, but also a powerful non-blocking web server, based on Python. And it's totally free and open-source.

For more infomation of tornado, you may visit the official docs: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 1):

see the django forms:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

and form validation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/